# How to serializer a customized query set result?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django model serializer, the typical use case is like below

```
class SalesManSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        module = models.SalesMan 
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

The id, name are all from the salse man  model.

But if I have another model called Order which referenced to SalseMan. I want to query how many order each sales man get.

The SQL would be like

```
SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(ORDER.ID) FROM SALSE_MAN, ORDER WHERE ORDER.UID = SALSE_MAN.ID GROUP BY SALSE_MAN.ID
```

How to serializer this query?

Answer (score 2):

Model serializers serialize only model fields by default. But good news is that you always can add custom fields to your serializer.

Don't know what your models exactly are, but in code it may look like:

```
class SalesManSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_orders = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        module = models.SalesMan
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'total_orders')
```

Serializers are responsible only for serializing. They don't construct querysets for us. That said you need to annotate query set yourself. Either in a view or wherever the queryset will be initialized and passed to the serializer you can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) to annotate object with count of orders.

For ex:

```
class SalesManViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SalesManSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SalesMan.objects.annotate(
            total_trucks = Count('orders'),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add it using a [methodfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class SalesManSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.SalesMan 
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'count')

    def get_count(self, instance):
        return Order.objects.count()
```

Comment: This is not efficient because it will perform 1 extra SQL query per SalesMan :(

Comment: @pythad yeah your answer is better, but my answer is fine for relatively small db.